# USB3 causing hangs

Tags: usb, drivers, motherboard, freeze, usb-3

I recently built my new computer and now i am facing constant system freezes that last a few seconds.

I narrowed the problem down to the USB3 drivers. I cannot just not use the drivers since all of my usb's in my motherboard are USB3.

I am wondering what i can do to resolve this issue?

I have already updated the drivers to the latest which did not resolve the issue.

I found this in the box that the motherboard came in, i am wondering if it was needed to be installed? and what it is for?
[image]

Motherboard: Asus Maxiumus VII Hero

Comment: An indication of your operating system would be helpful. If you're using Windows, see if the problem exists on a Linux Live CD: this would resolve whether the problem is in firmware or a driver.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: The cable is a converter 2.0 to 3.0 check the manual...

Comment: Your motherboard does indeed have USB 2.0

Comment: OS is Windows 7 x64;

The manual said nothing about this cord. and i do not think it is a converter..